# Both slices change if one is changed

Tags: go, slice

For some reason in Go, both slices change if I change either of them

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    )
func deleteAr(s []string, index int) []string{
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}

func main() {

var letters =[] string {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}
fmt.Println("original")

fmt.Println(letters)
var fletters =[] string {}

letters= deleteAr(letters, sort.StringSlice(letters).Search("E"))

fletters=letters
fmt.Println("after assigning but nothing changed in either slices")

fmt.Println(letters)
fmt.Println(fletters)

fletters = deleteAr(fletters , sort.StringSlice(fletters).Search("A"))
fletters = append(fletters , "b")
fmt.Println("after assigning deleting A and appending b to only fletters, but why letters changed too?")

fmt.Println(letters)
fmt.Println(fletters)

}
```

### result:

original

> [A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z]
>
> after assigning but nothing changed in either slices
>
> [A B C D F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z]
>
> [A B C D F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z]
>
> after assigning deleting A and appending b to only fletters, but why letters changed too?
>
> [B C D F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z b]
>
> [B C D F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z b]

Comment: fletters and letters are both references to the same slice. `fletters == letters // true`. To get the behavior you desire, you need a second slice e.g. `fletters := append([]string(nil), letters...)`.

Comment: That worked thank you, but why it behaves like that? I thought to have a slice referenced with another, you have to fletters = &letters

Comment: I'm not precisely sure what you're confused by, but maybe this will help. A variable is just a reference to something. In the above example you assigned `letters` to the slice of letters and `fletters` to an empty slice, and then correctly note that changing one does not change the other. You then assign `fletters` to the _same_ slice as `letters`. There is now only one slice, and the two variables reference the same slice. Any changes made to this slice (using either variable) will be reflected when accessed by either variable, since they both reference the same slice.

Comment: This is covered explicitly in the Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/8 . Going through the Tour of Go should help you to get a handle on the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slice is a view on an array. In your code, `letters` and `fletters` both refer to the same underlying array, so changes made to one is also visible to the other.

A slice will create a new array and copy the contents of the old one into the new one only as a result of `append` operation, and only if the capacity of the underlying array is not sufficient to hold the new elements. Your operations never require a change in the underlying array capacity, so the slices all point to the same underlying array.